# NSStatusItem and NSMenuItem detect shift press

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsstatusitem

I'm trying to modify my NSMenuItems in my NSStatusItem when the shift button is clicked. Basically I want to modify the text from "MenuItem123" to "Shift MenuItem123"

I tried adding

```
NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask
```

and

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask
```

which work for my regular window apps, but for NSStatusItem/NSMenuItems the completion blocks aren't called or are called but only when the menu isn't displayed.

Comment: do you want the menu item(s) updated only when the menu first opens, or continuously (while the user is moving the mouse down and the menu is visible, depending on if the user is touching the shift key or not)?  Also, are you setting up your status menu via a storyboard or xib or entirely programatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to listen to events in order to show alternate menu items. You only need create two menu items and mark the second one as alternate and also set its `keyEquivalentModifierMask` to `NSShiftKeyMask`. Assuming you have a variable called `statusItem` you can use the following code snippet:

```
let menu = NSMenu();

menu.addItemWithTitle("MenuItem123", action:"test:", keyEquivalent:"")
if let shiftItem = menu.addItemWithTitle("Shift MenuItem123", action:"test:", keyEquivalent:"") {
    shiftItem.alternate = true
    shiftItem.keyEquivalentModifierMask = Int(NSEventModifierFlags.ShiftKeyMask.rawValue)
}

statusItem.menu = menu
```

Comment: also minor change, had to use `Int(NSEventModifierFlags.ShiftKeyMask.rawValue)` instead